# How to interpret NA in GARCH std. errors and $t$-statistics in R?

Tags: r, time-series, garch

I'm trying to apply GARCH model to the RedHat market data using R.
When I use the `garchFit` function from the `fGarch` library I get the following results:

```
> garchFit(~garch(10,0),data=RedHatLogRet,trace=F)

Title:
 GARCH Modelling 

Call:
 garchFit(formula = ~garch(10, 0), data = RedHatLogRet, trace = F) 

Mean and Variance Equation:
 data ~ garch(10, 0)

Conditional Distribution:
 norm 

Coefficient(s):
        mu       omega      alpha1      alpha2      alpha3      alpha4      alpha5  
0.00098990  0.00024533  0.10983739  0.14223797  0.05749616  0.00155498  0.00000001  
    alpha6      alpha7      alpha8      alpha9     alpha10  
0.08477199  0.00060140  0.04391016  0.05989966  0.03876993  

Std. Errors:
 based on Hessian 

Error Analysis:
         Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
mu      9.899e-04   3.860e-04    2.565 0.010329 *  
omega   2.453e-04   1.455e-05   16.864  < 2e-16 ***
alpha1  1.098e-01   2.881e-02    3.813 0.000137 ***
alpha2  1.422e-01   4.356e-02    3.266 0.001093 ** 
alpha3  5.750e-02   3.269e-02    1.759 0.078587 .  
alpha4  1.555e-03   2.386e-02    0.065 0.948045    
alpha5  1.000e-08          NA       NA       NA    
alpha6  8.477e-02   3.121e-02    2.717 0.006596 ** 
alpha7  6.014e-04   7.643e-03    0.079 0.937281    
alpha8  4.391e-02   3.107e-02    1.413 0.157608    
alpha9  5.990e-02   2.438e-02    2.457 0.014010 *  
alpha10 3.877e-02   2.697e-02    1.437 0.150598    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log Likelihood:
 6613.981    normalized:  2.438784
```

As you can see model seems to be appropriate but I'm confused with `alpha5`'s NA stats. How to interpret these results?

For more information, here are the squared residuals' ACF and PACF plots based on an ARMA model: [ACF plot of squared residuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxfyz.jpg), [PACF plot of squared residuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUI35.jpg).

Comment: To me it looks like that is due to the coefficient 'alpha5' being so small in magnitude. It may be that when a coefficient is virtually nonexistent after optimizing the likelihood function the smallest value at the shown decimals is returned (1.00e08) and thus no standard error is calculated. Or it is too small and thus exempt. You would need to check out what exactly happens in the code of the package you are using.